# Junit Suites with Spring autowired elements

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have a collection of Junit test classes with an autowired element (Spring). If I execute each Junit test class separately, everything works ok.

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TestClass {

@Autowired
MyController control;

@Test
public void geolocTest() throws Exception {
...
}
```

I want to create a "Test Suite", but if I execute the Test Suite, it looks like the autowired elements are "null", so every test fails.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        TestClass.class
})
public class TestSuit extends TestCase {
...
}
```

What can I do? Thanks

**NOTE:**
What I want is to execute a code before all test classes, and another code after all test classes. I think I need a Suite for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you should use:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

You can use @Before, @After, @BeforeClass, @AfterClass.

First two will be executed before and after each test case in a given Test class.

Last two will be executed only once per given Test class.

Your tests should be atomic as much as possible, so if you have all Test cases mutually dependent on same data or order of execution, try to rewrite this first.

If you wish to share some application properties, the good thing, for auto wiring between all test cases, such as the urls to mocks, take a look at the Spring profiles.

You can then have production specific and test specific properties which will be injected based on the current profile.

Take a look at the example and official docs:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@Profile("test")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/yourApp.properties")
public class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

You can then injected shared properties from the file in your test classes like this:

```
@Value("${mock.url}")
private String mockUrl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your missing at least the following

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

on your TestClass.

Comment: If I write that, the tests are executed 2 times. (One execution by the Suite and another one by the self-test).

Comment: In general Suits are not used to often, because most build tools and IDEs have a functionality to execute all tests. I assume your doing that and thats maybe the reason why it gets executed two times.

Comment: What I want is to execute a code before all test classes, and another code after all test classes. I think I need a Suite to do this...

Comment: Than let spring do the job for you? Add a configuration class with a postconstruct method which is only active in a test environment. For that take a look into Profiles and active profiles. (There are multiple ways to run something in a test only)